# Unable to Screenshot using keyboard shortcut on elementary OS 0.4 Loki

Tags: release-loki, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

I recently installed elementary OS 0.4 Loki.

The language of my OS is English but I use the Spanish (from Spain) keyboard.

I've been using elementary OS since Luna and this hasn't happened to me before.

When I try to take a Screenshot using the usual/standard key on the keyboard, I get nothing. No sound, no screenshot, nothing.

I check the Keyboard Settings and saw this:

[image: screenshot of my keyboard settings shortcuts regarding screenshot]
Prior to this I haven't done a single edit to my Keyboard Settings, yet Take a Screenshot appears to be Disabled. If I try to set the Print key nothings happens, it just says disabled and stays that way.

I tried to put a random combination (Ctrl+P) but it did nothing, all I hear is a faint sound of warning and it doesn't take the picture.

The app itself does works normally, although I miss the "camera-shutter-sound" it used to make.

Answer (score 11):

Actually this issue touches two different bugs in Loki:

1. [Printscreen "PrtScn" button doesn't actually take a screenshot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/screenshot-tool/+bug/1622224)
2. [Custom keyboard shortcuts not working, loki fresh install](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1622298)

Comment: As a workaround in the meantime you can open the applications menu, type "screenshot-tool -r", then press enter.

Comment: To add to Seth's comment: `screenshot-tool -r` takes a screenshot of a region, saving to a file, and `screenshot-tool -rc` saves it to the clipboard. Further options are listed by `screenshot-tool --help`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug, you can check it out here https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1622298

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this problem, which I think has two parts.

1. It appears that the PrintSc button itself is not mapped. I have successfully mapped Ctrl+0 to work with gnome-screenshot, but when I tried to map PrintSc to the command, it didn't work.
2. It appears that the native Print Screen command doesn't work. I thought that if I could map Ctrl+0 to the gnome-screenshot command, then it would work, but when I tried to do this through the keyboard shortcuts menu, it did not work.