# Where are the screenshots saved to in 0.4?

Tags: system

I'm trying to take a screenshot with my keyboard, I'm clicking Alt+PrtScr like normal, I hear a bleeping sound but no screenshot is saved in the Pictures folder.

I checked with dconf Editor as suggested in this stackoverflow question [Change the folder where screenshots are saved](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/5384/change-the-folder-where-screenshots-are-saved) but I can't find the gnome-screenshot option for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Loki, which is not allowing to take the screenshot. The Question has been asked [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7703/unable-to-screenshot-using-keyboard-shortcut-on-elementary-os-0-4-loki) earlier. And the Bug too has been [confirmed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-keyboard/+bug/1622298).